# Qual o comportamento quando MongoDB chega ao valor máximo definido de $inc?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, value

Qual é o comportamento quando Mongo atinge seu valor máximo para findAndModify com parâmetros abaixo, como posso reiniciar para 0 quando isso acontecer?

```
        db.collection('count').findAndModify(
        { "_id": "xy" },
        [["_id", 1]],
        { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
        {new: true, 'upsert': true},
    function(err,doc) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(doc.value.seq);
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to **Stack Overflow in Portuguese**. This question appears to be in English and this is the SO Portuguese community. If you're looking to get help in English, please visit - [**Stack Overflow in English**](http://stackoverflow.com)  If you're looking to get help in Portuguese, please [**edit**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/76617/edit) and translate your question.

Comment: Não esqueça de [edit] o título.